# Google Analytics Acquisition Report shows negative change

Tags: google-analytics, search-engine

I am generating google analytics Acquisition report and comparing previous 2 month to the current month. Although the numbers in the current month is higher, but google looks at it as a negative growth. 
Isn't it suppose to be a positive change when it shows you have for example, you have more direct users? (Here is a screenshot)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top right of your report probably look like this:
[image]

Note it says: May 1st to June 30th compared to July 1st to Aug 31st.

Percentage change is calculated by calculating the "change", change is calculated by using the current number subtracted by the number you're comparing to.

In this case, the current number is the number in the May 1st to June 30th period and the compared to number is the number between July 1st to Aug 31st. Which is about 26k and 27.8k respectively. Thus change is `26k - 27.8k = -1.8k`

The percentage increase is calculated by change (-1.8k) divided by the compare to (27.8k) the number, which yields you `-6.29%` as shown.

If you want to show it being positive, you need to make the July 1st to Aug 31st your current period.

Comment: By answering off-topic questions, we will encourage them to ask more off-topic questions